# Close another app from your app?

Tags: android, android-intent

I want to close another app opened from my app with *intent* ... 
**On my app i create an intent to open Google Maps, but i want to close this Google Maps with Buton on my app.**
Is it posible? 
Thank you guys!

Comment: If the Google Maps Activity ended up in your app's Activity stack you might be able to get rid of it e.g. by restarting your current Activity with [`FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP` | `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent#FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP)

Comment: No, i launch Google Maps but i have a Bubble button (overlap screens service)that  launch my app when im on Google Maps ... And i want to close Google Maps of my device when i press another button from my app again

Comment: Well, have you verified that the Activities really aren't on the same Activity stack (e.g. using `adb shell dumpsys activity`)?

Comment: Yes , its not ... I search and its not posible to close another app from my app

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is **not possible** to close the another app from your app.

It is ethically not correct and there is no official Android API as well.

Answer (score 3):

You can only close the *background processes* of other apps, you are no longer able to close their main activities.

Declare a permission for that in your **AndroidManifest** file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.KILL_BACKGROUND_PROCESSES" />
```

**APP:**

```
ActivityManager manager = (ActivityManager)getSystemService(Activity.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
manager.killBackgroundProcesses(packageName);
```

I had used this code, that was worked for me.

Hope this can help you, thanks.

Comment: Didnt work for me :( On my app i launch Google Maps and i have an overlap screen Bubble button than re launch my app on background , but o want to close the opened Maps when i click on another button... I try some things but i think its not possible , i search more things and nothing... But it could be a nice answer to another people! ^^

Comment: Sorry if I can't understand you then I'm apologize. I already mention, Now(after Android 2.2) you can only close 'background processes of other apps'. You can't close another app main activity. Before android 2.2 It was possible, Thanks.

Comment: @HasibAkter why did you post this answer if it is not relevant? Also Who is using Android 2.2 now? Why are confusing more with this explanation?

Comment: I'm not confuse you, you can't close another app but you can close background processes of other apps process is available. Many time another app some service can run background in your app, you can close those background process.

Answer (score 0):

In the past, for third party Apps not designed for this, I have used:
`activity.startActivityForResult(intent, requestCode);`
and then done a:
`activity.finishActivity(requestCode);`
using the same requestCode to stop the Activity.  You should receive a resultcode == RESULT_CANCELED to:
`protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)`
if you wish to know it finished.
It tends to produce a clunky result though.